Regex to catch Excel sheet line index excluding sheet name having digit and other digits
This is my first question on StackOverflow. :)
I work with an Excel file, I need to duplicate formulas on each line so I need to change line indexes in these formulas for each new line.
For that, I wrote a regex to catch the sheet line index in formula, excluding other digits not refering to a line index (ex: "=2024-17-04") and excluding sheet name having digit (ex: "MATMAS05").
It works pretty well except on the "excluding sheet name having digit" part.
I wrote this regex: [A-Z]((?!MATMAS05)|(?<!"))+(\d+)(?!").
And I have these formula examples where the line index to catch is 5:
SI(F5="";"";"Z_PACK_TYPE")
MARKET!A5
MARKET!MQ5
MARKET!AB5
MARKET!TX5
MARKET!SX5
MATMAS05!CZ5="3200";MARKET!DA5
SI(MATMAS05!CZ5="3200";MATMAS05!CZ5="3200";MARKET!DA5;"")
SI(L5="";"";"STRING")
SI(MATMAS05!CZ5="3300";MARKET!DA5;"")
SI(ESTVIDE(MARKET!EG5);"";SI(MATMAS05!CZ5="3200";MARKET!EG5;""))

To test my regex, I created a regex101 save that I share to you the related regex101.
But as you can see, my regex also catches the "5" of my sheet name "MATMAS05".
I would like to exclude the sheet name "MATMAS05" from my catches.
Do you know what is missing in my regex in that goal?

I think you just want ![A-Z]+(\d+), see https://regex101.com/r/PHCBkF/4. If all your references contain sheet names, this will work.

If there are false positives inside quotes, you might - in 99.9% of cases - get away with "[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|![A-Z]+(\d+)

@WiktorStribiżew
I forgot to add another formula example where I don't have sheet name inside.
In that case, the ![A-Z]+(\d+) does not work.

Try https://regex101.com/r/PHCBkF/6, the Group 1 value is what you need.

It's weird because it seems to work well when I look on regex101 but I try it on PHP code with a preg-match, script doesn't always find the line index number.
You can see it in this online saved script https://onlinephp.io/c/c2fd6
Only formulas without sheet names are well processed, in other cases only the sheet name is returned by the preg_match function. Do you know why?

So you are doing it in PHP, nice. Try $regex = '/(?:(?<!")(?:"")*"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|\w+!)(*SKIP)(*F)|\b[A-Z]+\K\d+\b/'; if you need to return just the numbers. If you need to get ALL matches, use preg_match_all($regex, $formula, $matches);

See this fiddle.

Is this what you're looking for: https://regex101.com/r/W99ncx/1 ?

@Dunois With this regex, the L5 cell ( SI(L5="";"";"Z_LIFE_CYCLE_SG") ) is not catch. I need to catch the line index with and without sheet name before, in the order to increase them in the formula for my next line.

And my fiddle? Have you seen it?

@NicolasC then just make the regular expression more specific, like so: https://regex101.com/r/anTyqH/1 . If the CZ5s in SI(MATMAS05!CZ5="3200";MATMAS05!CZ5="3200";MARKET!DA5;"") also need to be captured along with the DA5 then use something like this: https://regex101.com/r/ThbdM7/1 .

Please also look at @WiktorStribiżew 's solution. It is implemented in PHP and seems to do exactly what you need.

You can use
<?php
// Enter your code here, enjoy!
$formulas = [
    'SI(F5="";"";"Z_PACK_TYPE")',
    'MARKET!A5',
    'MARKET!MQ5',
    'MARKET!AB5',
    'MARKET!TX5',
    'MARKET!SX5',
    'MATMAS05!CZ5="3200";MARKET!DA5',
    'SI(MATMAS05!CZ5="3200";MATMAS05!CZ5="3200";MARKET!DA5;"")',
    'SI(L5="";"";"STRING")',
    'SI(MATMAS05!CZ5="3300";MARKET!DA5;"")',
    'SI(ESTVIDE(MARKET!EG5);"";SI(MATMAS05!CZ5="3200";MARKET!EG5;""))',
];

$regex = '/(?:(?<!")(?:"")*"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|\w+!)(*SKIP)(*F)|\b[A-Z]+\K\d+\b/';

foreach ($formulas as $formula) {
    preg_match_all($regex, $formula, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}

See the PHP demo.
The regex is
(?:(?<!")(?:"")*"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|\w+!)(*SKIP)(*F)|\b[A-Z]+\K\d+\b

See the regex demo. Details:
Details:

(?:(?<!")(?:"")*"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|\w+!)(*SKIP)(*F) - matches and skips:

(?<!")(?:"")*"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*" - a substring between two " chars with quote-escaped " inside
| - or
\w+! - one or more word chars and then a ! char


| - or
\b[A-Z]+\K\d+\b - a word boundary, one or more ASCII uppercase letters, \K omits the matched chars and then one or more digits followed with a word boundary are matched and consumed.


Thank you @wiktor-stribiżew.
Your formula works perfectly.
Thank you for your fast and effective help.
